# after movement have ceased (Steinbeck)

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood, ellipses, typographical-errors

John Steinbeck, *Travels with Charley* (1962):

> "That discussion, however, did not go into the life span of journeys. This seems to be variable and unpredictable. Who has not known a journey to be over and dead before the traveller returns? The reverse is also true: *many a* trip continues long after **movement** in time and space **have ceased**."

Why did Steinbeck use "**have** (ceased)" in the above quote rather than "**has** (ceased)," which is the third-person singular present form of the (auxiliary) verb and agrees with the person of the subject of the clause "movement," which is an uncountable noun?

I supposed, judging from the use of the rather archaic literary expression "Many a...," as well as the placement of the sentence being after a colon, making it stand out from the rest of the text, that the verb "have" is in the present subjunctive mood, which is also an archaic literary expression, as in the following older examples:

- The Magazine of Science, and School of Arts Volume 3 (1842): "If it **be** exposed to heat , after it
  **have undergone** this change, it swells up...."
- Australia and New Zealand (1876): “even after he **have maintained** himself for some weeks in each year....”
- The Lutheran Witness Volumes 3-5 (1884): “and
  Grasshopper he never put up food for winter; and so when winter **come**
  and he got nothing to eat....”
- **Come** winter, we'll have to pay a good deal more for vegetables and fruit. ['When winter comes,...']

Is my conjecture correct? If not, for what else reason did Steinbeck use "have"? Could it be some form of ellipsis or a simple case of typo?

Comment: [Many a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/many%20a%2Fan) is formal but it's not archaic: it's found in plenty of 21st century texts ([example](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/articles/gluten_free_budget)).

Comment: He took them for a 'they' instead of an 'it' (as suggested). And Steinbeck is of biblical proportions whenever possible, huge, even on vacation.

Comment: I suspect the quote from the Lutheran Witness is [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) or an imitation thereof, not a subjunctive.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't need to be subjunctive; it's a plural verb because it's a plural subject:

> movement in time and space

can be taken as a shortened form of

> movement in time and movement in space

with the repeated "movement" elided.

Comment: Then why did he not use the plural "movements (in time and space)"?

Comment: @Expressivist: That would perhaps be a more usual (and less "literary") construction, but it would express something slightly different. "Movements" (plural) suggests a series of movements considered separate/distinct; the singular is used when referring to the idea of movement, or to movements that are considered as part of one whole.

Comment: Can you find authoritative support (other than Steinbeck) for the acceptability of the deletion 'movement in time and space have ceased' from 'movement in time and movement in space have ceased'? 'Movement, both in time and space, has ceased' might be a better way of avoiding one problem or the other ('misagreement' / pluralising what is better kept as a noncount usage).

Comment: @psmears Is this kind of ellipsis ("movement in time and [movement in] space have ceased"), if valid at all, acceptable only in literary expressions, or could it be grammatically acceptable in general writing?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I haven't looked (because it seemed acceptable, if rather literary-sounding, to me), and it's surprisingly hard to search for examples. Your suggestion would certainly be preferable in most contexts; I'm not sure I'm going to argue whether your suggestion is better than what Steinbeck wrote!

Comment: @Expressivist: I've tried searching for examples, to check how common this is in different types of writing, but it's surprisingly hard to search for (nor do I have a lot of time to try, sadly). I'd say it comes across very literary in style, so I'd avoid it (and use something like what EdwinAshworth suggested) in other contexts.

Comment: It is an extraordinary usage.  It is indeed, as already suggested, highly literary.  What is it doing?  It brings the reader up short:  in its three final iambs as well as in its sense.  Travel happens in time as well as in space.  And not only in the obvious sense that the physical act of travelling takes time as well as covering distance.  The depth of travel includes the stationary time in places, meeting people and roaming in cities.  This is an opinion for what little it is worth, but I think it conveys more and more deeply and briefly than strict grammar might permit.

Comment: @Tuffy So "in time / and space / _have_ ceased" constitutes an iambic trimeter (?) but using "_has_" doesn't?

Comment: @Exp No, I would not say that.  You are right that it could be looked at in that way:  after all, there are three iambs.  Iambic trimeter was the rhythm used for the dialogue sections in all but one of the surviving Greek tragedies.  But for prose a sentence can have a rhythmic ending without being formally metric.  Such endings were a stock in trade for the first century BCE jurist and orator, Marcus Tullius Cicero.  Metre is associated with a repeated rhythmic pattern.  The rhetorical use of rhythmic ending to prose passages was known in ancient times as 'clausula' (a 'closer').

Comment: @Tuffy Hum. I still don't see much of a difference, literary or otherwise, in using "have" in place of "has," other than making it look strange or unfamiliar, if not an outright typo. But I am quite amazed that quite a few English speakers here seem to accept it as a valid form of literary expression. I wonder if it's because of the name of Steinbeck.

Comment: I'd mark 'Work in the mines and quarries have virtually ceased' with an asterisk, even if Tolkien wrote it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: another example, found on the Internet "lack of time and motivation are the most common barriers that inhibit exercise adherence." You can't say "lacks" because "lack" is a mass noun. And you can't say "is" because the end of the sentence treats "lack of time" and "lack of motivation" as two different things.

Comment: @Peter Shor According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lack), 'lack' has been countified, but I agree that it doesn't sound too hot in the plural, especially in the 'lack of ...' phrase (which is often used with a definite article, even with multiple NPs following).

Comment: @Exp:  Yes, you make a fair point.  I do not seem to have answered your question.  I shall be in trouble for this, and I have no strictly grammatical defence.  I think that movement in time and movement in space are, in the mind of Steinbeck, different sorts of movement, one through space and the other through time.  It is as if he is forcing together the south poles of two magnets.  So he is certainly (to continue the metaphor) straining the grammar.  You could, though, treat the two prepositional phrases as adverbial to a kind of verbal noun - "movement".

Comment: @PeterShor: Nice find! My own search turned up one example in COCA: "God's work of creation and redemption are united (57:291)" but I could easily believe that one is just a typo. And the limit on searches per day on COCA meant I had to stop hunting for more :(.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that Steinbeck is using the subjunctive mood here. In current English, that mood doesn't normally appear after the subordinator "after". (Your second and third examples, which use "after" and "when", were written many decades before Steinbeck's text, so they are of little relevance. The first and fourth examples use the subjunctive mood for very different reasons.)

I'd also argue against assuming that some elements have been omitted ("after movement in time and [[movement in]] space have ceased"), as another answer suggests. It would be correct, for example, to write "the house of Alice and Bob is green" though writing "the house of Alice and Bob are green" would normally be considered an error. (Note that the same is true even if we use a mass noun: *"Luggage from Hermes and Coach are stylish." *"Research into gravity and electromagnetism are ongoing.")

I don't see any other reason that might justify "have ceased", so in this case I think that Steinbeck (or perhaps an editor, publisher, etc.) simply made a grammar mistake. It happens.

Comment: Would there still be a decent number of native English speakers who find the sentence "The house of Alice and Bob _are_ green." acceptable if they were told it was written by some notable author like Steinbeck?

Comment: @Exp I expect that in that case, more people would consider that sentence to be correct than otherwise, but I still think that they would constitute a small minority. Americans (and I'm sure other English speakers, too) are taught from a young age that such sentences are wrong, and everyone knows that no writer is infallible.

Comment: @Exp: That example is different, because "house" is a count noun, and "movement" (in this instance) is a mass noun. So there is a semantic reason for wanting to use the singular, which does not apply in the "house" case.

Comment: @psmears Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to account for the use of a mass noun.

Comment: I'd agree; I'd say that Steinbeck was pushing notional agreement too far. With more common non-count usages, we wouldn't say 'Work in the mines and quarries have virtually ceased' or 'Money in ISAs and related products are tax-shrouded'.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I would consider "research into gravity and electromagnetism are ongoing" acceptable but to have a different meaning than "research into gravity and electromagnetism is ongoing". The first makes it clear that these two areas of research are ongoing separately, whereas the second is consistent with "gravity and electromagnetism" being a single area of research.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime I wonder whether you're British (or a speaker of another non-American dialect), because BrE speakers tend to use plural verbs more often with singular subjects. (Often that's with collective nouns, but still.) Steinbeck, of course, was American, so I'd think that practice wouldn't appeal much to him.

Answer (score 3):

[psmears’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609242/2587) gives the somewhat plausible suggestion that *movement in time and space* can be read as an ellipsis for *movement in time and movement in space*, giving *have* a plural subject.

But it seems to me at least as plausible that **this is simply an error**, by either Steinbeck or his typesetters.  Intentional ellipsis of this form is extremely rare, even in literary usage (as discussed in comments to psmears’ answer) — but seen as an error, this is a very common kind in both speech and writing, mistakenly inflecting a verb to agree with a noun phrase linearly adjacent to it (the plural “…time and space…”) instead of its intended syntactic subject (the singular “…movement…”).